# SQL query to create aging report for bugs when they were open

Tags: mysql, sql

I am creating an Aging report for bugs open for "30-60days","60-90days","3-6months" and "6+months" for each Quarter. If a bug was created in Q-1 and is still open in Q-2 and if it satisfies the above condition it should be counted in the above buckets for Q-2

```
select Category,
       SUM(CASE WHEN Bugs_open_days > 29 and Bugs_open_days < 61 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as bucket_30_60,
       SUM(CASE WHEN Bugs_open_days > 60 and Bugs_open_days < 91 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as bucket_60_90,
       SUM(CASE WHEN Bugs_open_days > 90 and Bugs_open_days < 181 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as bucket_3_6,
       SUM(CASE WHEN Bugs_open_days >= 181 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as bucket_6monthplus
from (
select Created_Quarter,
       Category,
       bug_id,
       Resolved_Count_In_Days,
       Resolved_Count_In_Days - 1 as Bugs_open_days
from TableA)
group by 1

On Date Category 30-60 days 60-90 days  3-6 months  6+ months
2018-03-31 P       0                             0   0  
2018-03-31 G       6          5              0       0
2018-03-31 W       4         10              0       0
2018-03-31 GM      16        12              0       0
2018-03-31 null    3          2              0       0
2018-06-30                  
2018-06-30                  
2018-06-30                  
2018-06-30                  
2018-06-30                  
2018-06-30                  
2018-09-30                  
2018-09-30                  
2018-09-30                  
2018-09-30                  
2018-09-30                  
2018-09-30                  
2018-12-31                  
2018-12-31                  
2018-12-31                  
2018-12-31                  
2018-12-31                  
2018-12-31                  
2019-03-31                  
2019-03-31                  
2019-03-31                  
2019-03-31                  
2019-03-31                  
2019-03-31
```

Comment: 1) MySQL and SQL Server are different dbms. Which one are you using? 2) Your expected output doesn't seem to match your query at all. What are you really expecting?

Comment: I am using MySQL, wanted help in creating a query to pull the desired output

Comment: If a bug was created on 1/1/2019 and was closed on 4/30/2019, that'd be around 89 days the bug was open. At the end of Q1, you'd include that under `30-60 days`, correct? At the end of Q2, would you report it under `60-90 days`?

Comment: Yes...based on end of each quarter I need the status